# JPA 2 Relationship JOIN Named Query

Tags: sql, jpa-2.0, named-query

I'm using SpringBoot 2.4 with JPA 2.0 and I have a Model like following:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Nation {
   @Id 
   @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "nation")
   private List<Country> country;
}
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Country {
   @Id 
   @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne
   private Nation nation;
}
```

Now I would to like to find all `Nation` filtered by their `ID` and by `country` `ID`. In pure `SQL` is simply something like:

```
select * from nation n, country c where n.id = [nation_id] AND c.id = [country_id];
```

Therefore I thought about doing this way with JPA:

```
@Query("select n from Nation n JOIN n.country c where n.id = ?1 AND c.id = ?2)
public List<Nation> find(Integer nationID, Integer countryID);
```

But it doesn't work; it is filtered by Nation but not by countries.

If I print the `Hibernate` generate SQL by adding:

```
spring.jpa.show.sql=true
```

I can see that the query is exactly the same I posted above in pure SQL. The problem occours when I invoke `nation.getCountry()`, it generates another query that load all country connected to given Nation id.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use JPA DTO [projections](https://thorben-janssen.com/dto-projections/?utm_source=social&utm_medium=facebook&utm_campaign=tutorial) for this case ...

So, in your Nation class create a constructor like this:

```
 /**
  * Copy Constructor. It creates a "detached" copy of the
  * given nation with only a copy of the provided country.
  */
 public Nation(Nation n, Country c) {
     super();
     this.id = n.id;
     // copy other nation values ...

     this.country.add( new Country(c) );
 }
```

Modify your query to invoke such constructor ... something like this (assuming that `Nation` is declared in the java package `my.domain`):

```
@Query("select new my.domain.Nation(n, c) from Nation n JOIN n.country c where n.id = ?1 AND c.id = ?2)
```

**Disclaimer:**

- I have done this using JPA and hibernate. So far, I haven't tested with spring, but I guess this does not matter because your JPA provider is probably hibernate too.
- I have done this using only parts (or attributes) of the target entities (as described in the provided link) ... I never have pass the full entities (as I suggest to do in the query). Let me explain, in the cases where I have applied this, I have a constructor like `Nation(String name, int population)` and in the query I do something like: `SELECT new my.domain.Nation(n.name, c.population) ...` Try to pass the full entities to see if it works ... if it fails, fallback to create a constructor that receives only the attributes that you require for your business case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Calitos Way. I will try your solution, I'm still little bit confusing about `Transaction` and `Lazy` or `Eager` properties. Should `@OneToMany` be `Eager` by default? If I start my application with embedded SpringBoot tomcat I must annotated my method with `@Transactional` to retrieve the list of `Country` associated to my `Nation` entity. Don't they should be loaded by default?

Comment: Normally, it is a good practice to make your relationships as LAZY as possible (I mean to avoid to use EAGER). When you annotated a relationship as EAGER, you instruct to the JPA Provider (hibernate) to load the relationship just after loading the entity that declares it. That could be a performance penalty is you're not planning to use such relation is your business case. However, it could be cases where the use of EAGER is justified (for example, if you're sure a entity always needs the relationship, not matter what).

Comment: Regarding your question ... the answer is "it depends". By default, Spring implements a feature called: [Open Session in View](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view) ... This feature allows you to load your relationships outside of a  `@Transactional` context ... Some people [think](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/) this feature is prone to performance problems if the developer is not aware of it ...